# SQL - how to consolidate Or statements

Tags: sql, sql-server

There must be a better way to write the query below, if you have any suggestions please let me know.

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    [eSDR_Full].[dbo].[course_register]
WHERE
    broad_field_code = '08'  
    AND narrow_field_code = '05' 
    AND detail_field_code = '05' 
    AND end_month is null 
    AND disabled <> 'Y'

    OR broad_field_code = '08' 
    AND narrow_field_code = '05' 
    AND detail_field_code = '05'
    AND end_month > '201512' 
    AND disabled <> 'Y'

    OR broad_field_code = '08' 
    AND narrow_field_code = '05' 
    AND detail_field_code = '05' 
    AND end_month is null 
    AND disabled is null

    OR broad_field_code = '08' 
    AND narrow_field_code = '05' 
    AND detail_field_code = '05'
    AND end_month > '201512' 
    AND disabled is null

ORDER BY
    end_month DESC
```

Comment: All the terms separated by OR have `broad_field_code = '08' and narrow_field_code = '05' and detail_field_code = '05'`, so you could distribute those out.

Answer (score 2):

First refactoring:

```
SELECT *
  FROM [eSDR_Full].[dbo].[course_register]
  Where (broad_field_code = '08' and narrow_field_code = '05' and detail_field_code = '05')
     and (   (end_month is null and disabled <> 'Y')
          or (end_month > '201512' and disabled <> 'Y')
          or (end_month is null and disabled is null)
          or (end_month > '201512' and disabled is null))
 order by end_month desc
```

This makes it clear that you have a common prefix to all the conditions.

Second refactoring takes advantage of other commonalities:

```
SELECT *
  FROM [eSDR_Full].[dbo].[course_register]
  Where (broad_field_code = '08' and narrow_field_code = '05' and detail_field_code = '05')
     and (end_month is null or end_month > '201512')
     and (disabled is null or disabled <> 'Y')
 order by end_month desc
```

Now it's clear that we just have a series of stacked ANDs based on simple conditions of one column each, so we can do this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM [eSDR_Full].[dbo].[course_register]
  Where broad_field_code = '08' 
    and narrow_field_code = '05' 
    and detail_field_code = '05'
    and coalesce(end_month, '999999') > '201512'
    and coalesce(disabled, 'N') <> 'Y')
 order by end_month desc
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM [eSDR_Full].[dbo].[course_register]
WHERE broad_field_code = '08' 
    AND narrow_field_code = '05' 
    AND detail_field_code = '05' 
    AND (end_month IS NULL OR end_month > '201512')
    AND ISNULL(disabled,'') != 'Y'
ORDER BY end_month DESC
```